# meteor-typeahead: Listing and selecting

Tags: node.js, meteor

I have installed meteor-typeahead via npm. https://www.npmjs.org/package/meteor-typeahead
I have also installed

```
meteor add sergeyt:typeahead
```

from https://atmospherejs.com/sergeyt/typeahead

I am trying to get the data-source attribute example to function so I can display a list of countries when the user begins to type. I have inserted all countries into the collection :-

```
Country = new Meteor.Collection('country');
```

The collection is published and subscribed.

When I type into the input field, no suggestions appear. Is it something to do with activating the API? if so how do I do this? Please reference the website https://www.npmjs.org/package/meteor-typeahead

My form looks like this:

```
<template name="createpost">
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="createpost">
        <input class="form-control typeahead" name="country" type="text" placeholder="Country" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="off" data-source="country"/>
        <input  type="submit" value="post">
</form>
</template>
```

client.js

```
Template.createpost.helpers({
country: function(){
    return Country.find().fetch().map(function(it){ return it.name; });
} });
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to make your input to have typeahead completion you need:

1. Activate typeahead jQuery plugin using package API

   - Meteor.typeahead call in template rendered event handler.
   - Meteor.typeahead.inject call to activate typeahead plugin for elementes matched by CSS selector available on the page (see [demo app](https://github.com/sergeyt/meteor-typeahead/blob/master/demo/demo.js#L165)).
2. Write 'data-source' function in your template understandable by typeahead plugin. It seems your 'data-source' function is correct.
3. Add CSS styles for typeahead input(s)/dropdown to your application. See example [here](https://github.com/sergeyt/meteor-typeahead/blob/master/demo/style.css) in demo app.

Comment: Thanks Sergeyt, I will go through the steps you mentioned.

Comment: Where does the Meteor.typeahead.inject(selector); code go? Sorry, I am very confused.

How do I call it?

Comment: Call it on DOM ready event, i.e. using Meteor.startup (demo app has a [sample call](https://github.com/sergeyt/meteor-typeahead/blob/master/demo/demo.js#L165)). Or call it in template rendered event handler.

Comment: How do I define the selector? I put  Meteor.typeahead.inject(selector); into the server startup. I get the following message, 
ReferenceError: selector is not defined 
. Would it be too much to ask if you create a file on github with the code specifically for the function only? It may make it easier for me to look at the code and learn what is going on.

Comment: @CodeCandy Meteor.typeahead.inject should be called inside client side since Meteor.typeahead package only works in browser environment.

Comment: Thanks for that. The demo app file has all the different types so and I'm having trouble in understanding what code is necessary. Which code references my Country collection which code does the prefetching. I'm so sorry for being a pain. I'm struggling with this since yesterday.

Comment: I have put the following into the client side startup. When I type into the input field, nothing comes up.
Meteor.startup(function(){
    Meteor.typeahead.inject();
    Meteor.subscribe('country');
    });

Comment: @sergeyt I'm having a hard time setting up the basic use of your package.
I used the following like you suggested:
if (Meteor.isClient){

  Meteor.startup(function(){
    // initializes all typeahead instances
    Meteor.typeahead.inject();
  });

}

Comment: @Ajar the package has helpful demo app, please look at it. Maybe you miss CSS styles that must be included to your app.

Comment: @sergeyt - thanks - I did cloned it and got it to work eventually, I had to use the inject line in the template rendered event rather then Meteor.startup() on the client... thanks a lot for the working example!

Answer (score 0):

Try this way in your template:

```
    <input type="text" name="country" data-source="country"
    data-template="country" data-value-key="name" data-select="selected">
```

Create template like country.html (for example /client/templates/country.html) which contains:

```
<template name="country">
    <p>{{name}}</p>
</template>
```

In your client javascript:

```
Template.createpost.rendered = function() {
    Meteor.typeahead.inject();
}
```

and

```
Template.createpost.helpers({
    country: function() {
    return Country.find().fetch().map(function(it){
            return {name: it.name};
        });
    },
    selected: function(event, suggestion, datasetName) {
        console.log(suggestion); //or anything what you want after selection
    }
})
```